# When switching values from 2 inputs, form is not binded as expected

Tags: forms, angular

I have a form (template-driven) with two fields and a button that switch the value of the fields.

Field's name are `data[0]` and `data[1]` with values `france` and `usa`.

When i click the switch button, the template render usa in `data[0]` and france in `data[1]` as expected. And when I submit the form I have `data[0]=france` and `data[1]=usa`.

**Expected behavior:**

I expect that the form has the same values as the template render so `data[0]=usa` and `data[1]=france`.

Here is a [plnkr to reproduce this](http://plnkr.co/PUqr4UF8V50594kyDL7I):

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, OnInit, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <my-form></my-form>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-form',
  template: `
    <h2>Switch input value and check or submit</h2>
    <form #myForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onsubmit($event, myForm)">
      <div *ngFor="let country of countries; let i = index">
      <input [ngModel]="country" name="data[{{i}}]" />
      </div>
      <button (click)="switch(myForm)">switch</button> <button (click)="switchAndPatch(myForm)">switch & patch</button> <br />
      <button (click)="checkOrder($event, myForm)" type="button">checkOrder</button>
      <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>

    <h2>List of countries that should be in same order than input</h2>
    <ol>
      <li *ngFor="let formCountry of formCountries; let i = index">field {{formCountry.fieldName}}: <strong>{{formCountry.label}}</strong></li>
    </ol>
  `,
})
export class FormComponent implements OnInit{
  countries = ['france', 'usa'];
  formCountries = []
  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.formCountries = []
    this.countries.forEach((country: string, i: number) => {
      this.formCountries[i] = {label: country, fieldName: `data[${i}]`}
    }
  }

  switch(form: NgForm){
    this.countries.reverse()
  }  

  switchAndPatch(form: NgForm){
    this.switch(form)

    this.countries.forEach((country: string, i: number) => {
      let newFormValues = {}
      newFormValues[`data[${i}]`] = country
      form.form.patchValue(newFormValues)
    })
  }

  checkOrder(ev, form: NgForm) {
    this.formCountries = []
    Object.keys(form.value).forEach((key: string, i: number) => {
      this.formCountries[i] = {label: form.value[key], fieldName: key}
    })

    console.log('checkOrder', this.countries, this.formCountries)
  }

  onsubmit(ev, form) {
    this.formCountries = []
    Object.keys(form.value).forEach((key: string, i: number) => {
      this.formCountries[i] = {label: form.value[key], fieldName: key}
    })

    console.log('onsubmit', this.countries, this.formCountries)
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App, FormComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Why there's button switching values and what is the expected?

Comment: why do you have two arrays?  `countries` and `formCountries`?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't see where in your form you are actually switching the values in the "data" array. That switch and patch thing doesn't seem (at first glance) to accomplish this. (I might also consider a different data structure, using indexes in arrays for this kind of thing is dicey). If I did go with an array, ultimately I probably wouldn't try re-ordering a live array as my data send, I'd create a new object/array, validate it, and send that.